# implementing css button in blogger blog

Tags: html, css, button, blogs, blogger

i am almost new to css and html, i usually search google for the code i needed and do some modification to work for me.

currently i want to implement a button in my blogger blog and here is how it works in example
Original button example
http://designshack.net/tutorialexamples/animatedDownload/index.html

whose css code is as follow.

```
.button a {
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;

  /*TYPE*/
  color: white;
  font: 17px/50px Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;

  /*GRADIENT*/  
  background: #00b7ea; /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #00b7ea 0%, #009ec3 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#00b7ea), color-stop(100%,#009ec3)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #00b7ea 0%,#009ec3 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #00b7ea 0%,#009ec3 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #00b7ea 0%,#009ec3 100%); /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(top, #00b7ea 0%,#009ec3 100%); /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00b7ea', endColorstr='#009ec3',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}

.button a, p {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
     -moz-border-radius: 10px;
          border-radius: 10px;

  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
     -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
          box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

p {
  background: #222;
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 180px; 
  margin: -50px 0 0 10px;

  /*TYPE*/
  text-align: center;
  font: 12px/45px Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;

  /*POSITION*/
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;

  /*TRANSITION*/  
  -webkit-transition: margin 0.5s ease;
     -moz-transition: margin 0.5s ease;
       -o-transition: margin 0.5s ease;
      -ms-transition: margin 0.5s ease;
          transition: margin 0.5s ease;
}

/*HOVER*/
.button:hover .bottom {
  margin: -10px 0 0 10px;
}

.button:hover .top {
  margin: -80px 0 0 10px;
  line-height: 35px;
}

/*ACTIVE*/
.button a:active {
background: #00b7ea; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #00b7ea 36%, #009ec3 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(36%,#00b7ea), color-stop(100%,#009ec3)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #00b7ea 36%,#009ec3 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #00b7ea 36%,#009ec3 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #00b7ea 36%,#009ec3 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(top,  #00b7ea 36%,#009ec3 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00b7ea', endColorstr='#009ec3',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

}

.button:active .bottom {
  margin: -20px 0 0 10px;
}

.button:active .top {
  margin: -70px 0 0 10px;
}
```

and here is html to use this css code.

```
<div class="button">
      <a href="#">Download</a>
      <p class="top">click to begin</p>
      <p class="bottom">1.2MB .zip</p>
    </div>
```

Now problem is that it does not work exactly as it should, i think that is because of p tag, it might have already defined in my template, so how can i use this p tag styling specific to this class only?
i hope you have got my point.
Looking forward.

Comment: Hi you want to this http://tinkerbin.com/BOi9zJeZ

Answer (score 0):

................***[Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/BOi9zJeZ)***

Hi now used to this css

```
.button {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 150px auto;
}

.button a {
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;

  /*TYPE*/
  color: white;
  font: 17px/50px Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;

  /*GRADIENT*/  
  background: #00b7ea; /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #00b7ea 0%, #009ec3 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#00b7ea), color-stop(100%,#009ec3)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #00b7ea 0%,#009ec3 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #00b7ea 0%,#009ec3 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #00b7ea 0%,#009ec3 100%); /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(top, #00b7ea 0%,#009ec3 100%); /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00b7ea', endColorstr='#009ec3',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}

.button a, p {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
     -moz-border-radius: 10px;
          border-radius: 10px;

  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
     -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
          box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

p {
  background: #222;
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 180px; 
  margin: -50px 0 0 10px;

  /*TYPE*/
  text-align: center;
  font: 12px/45px Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;

  /*POSITION*/
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;

  /*TRANSITION*/  
  -webkit-transition: margin 0.5s ease;
     -moz-transition: margin 0.5s ease;
       -o-transition: margin 0.5s ease;
      -ms-transition: margin 0.5s ease;
          transition: margin 0.5s ease;
}

/*HOVER*/
.button:hover .bottom {
  margin: -10px 0 0 10px;
}

.button:hover .top {
  margin: -80px 0 0 10px;
  line-height: 35px;
}

/*ACTIVE*/
.button a:active {
background: #00b7ea; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #00b7ea 36%, #009ec3 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(36%,#00b7ea), color-stop(100%,#009ec3)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #00b7ea 36%,#009ec3 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #00b7ea 36%,#009ec3 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #00b7ea 36%,#009ec3 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(top,  #00b7ea 36%,#009ec3 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00b7ea', endColorstr='#009ec3',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

}

.button:active .bottom {
  margin: -20px 0 0 10px;
}

.button:active .top {
  margin: -70px 0 0 10px;
}
```

***[LIve demo](http://tinkerbin.com/BOi9zJeZ)***

Comment: this is not working, i have already tried this code.visit my test blog here to see how it looks http://premium-stuff-guru.blogspot.com/2012/10/malwarebytes-anti-malware-pro-16501400.html